# Can mvc app can be deployed at azure, where the database is not deployed at azure but located at another server?

Tags: .net, azure

Our .net mvc project references a database that is hosted at a secure network area. At this point, our sql database cannot be deployed to azure. But we need to deploy our .net mvc 5 project at azure. Will this work? Will it be a successful deployment? We are worried as the database is at another location. Please share your insights and knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it can be done. Yes it will be a successful deployment! How fast are the connections depends on the network speed & latency...

Comment: There's no way for us to know whether your deployment will be "successful" - you'll have to contend with latency, potential firewall issues, etc. The only thing to suggest is to try it and test, to see if it works with expected performance levels, for you.

Comment: @HelderSepu - how can you be so confident it will be a successful deployment? There's no way to know this. Is the firewall open? Will it require a vpn (adding further speed reduction and latency increase)? Will the OP's company allow for the data to be transported over the Internet? Are there data sovereignty issues to contend with? Are there latency issues? On and on...

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm confident because I've done it!

Comment: @HelderSepu that's irrelevant. The OP's environment is a complete unknown to us (unless you happen to be on the OP's team or at the same company). There are *so many* factors that go into this. And there are many scenarios in which a solution involving an on-premises database is simply an impossibility.

Comment: Yep I know nothing about the environment... I'm assuming that he has full control over it, and in lack of details I like to stay positive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151432/discussion-between-heldersepu-and-david-makogon).

Comment: @HelderSepu: Wil you please provide an url that helped you to achieve your goal. I am very doubtful because of this msdn article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service.                                                                                         I think that this article is suggesting to use azure sql database with an app deployed in azure. We want to deploy our .net mvc  app to azure, but it is connected with a Sql server. We don't want to disturb our existing Sql  database; will someone share more insights please.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of url you are looking for... all you need is the connection string, if you don't have one ask your provider of the hosted at a secure network for one.

Comment: @HelderSepu: thank you. I meant url as online documentation from microsoft. We need to provide that msdn documentation url to our IT department. Anyways, I welcome others to answer or offer insights. We will try your suggestion as time comes. I will also present this question at azure forum. I will update my findings here. Thank you.

Comment: ...also David's suggestion is spot on ***try, test & see*** 90% of the time it works without any hiccups, if you get errors research them if no solution come back and post your error, and please be specific. This question was a bit broad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we found out some information. Web app ( deployed on Azure) can access on premise MS SQL Server. For this to happen, we need to configure our database and make our web application in certain way; for example, database with hybrid connection , membership database, etc. The following Microsoft document gives details:

[Microsoft online documentation link/url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server)

I am choosing this as answer because  my answer gives brief answer as well as provides detail online documentation link from Microsoft. Thank you.